# Running two kinds of backup at the same time

Tags: backup, sql-server-2005

I'm going to schedule a differential backup at 01AM and transaction log backup every one hour for a database. What will happen differential backup takes too long and transaction log backup starts while differential backup still running?

Also same question but with full backups. What will happen a transaction log backup starts while the database is still in the process of making a full backup?

If it matters, the scheduled jobs are going to run as sql scripts in management->plan->Execute T-SQL Statement Task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this blog post](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Search-Engine-QA-16-Concurrent-log-and-full-backups.aspx) from Paul Randal

From SQL 2005 onwards the log backup can run concurrently with the Full or Diff backup.